# Django session deletion effects another django application

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, session

I have two applications running on the same server with different ports and with their SQLite DB's are also different which is used to store user sessions data.

```
if request.session.exists(stored_session_key) and stored_session_key != request.session.session_key:
    Session.objects.get(session_key=stored_session_key).delete()
request.user.logged_in_user.session_key = request.session.session_key
request.user.logged_in_user.save()
```

I'm using this condition, to delete the previous session of the same user to logout from the previous device and keep login in the current device.

This was working as expected.

But I have two projects with the same logic.

**Problem:**

When I open two applications on the same browser(eg: In chrome, `tab-1:https://ip_address:8000`, `tab-2:https://ip_adress:8001`), I can able to login into one application at once. When I tried to login application two(even open login page of the application two), the application one is getting logged out.

Why this behavior and how to solve it?

**My assumption:**

Browser is sending different session_key, to the same running application when I log-in to a new application in the same browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the session cookie that is set for one application is then sent to the other application, because they are both running on the same hostname and path. Thus when you log into one application, it will set a session cookie that replaces any previous cookie, and you get logged out of the other application.

You have a few choices:

1. Run the two applications on different hostnames (different port is not sufficient).
2. Specify a different [`SESSION_COOKIE_NAME`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name) for one of your applications.
3. Use a different path for all the URLs on one of your applications, and then configure [`SESSION_COOKIE_PATH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#session-cookie-path) on that application, so that its session cookies are separate from the other app.